# How can i use plain SQL Queries in Laravel (5.*)? Or Shoul i learn ORMs?

Tags: node.js, laravel-5

I am developing a kind of application using laravel and i want to use SQL Queries
(They make things easier for me like in NodeJS while some prefer using ORMs).

How can i do this in laravel? Or should i use ORMs like Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use via ORM and non-RAW query.

but if you want to use then you can try in this way.

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * 
                                FROM some_table 
                                WHERE some_col = '$someVariable'
                               ") 
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks Man, When developing a complex app, i prefer RAW SQL Queries!!!

Comment: Yes no doubt it reduce effort and time.